# How can I copy and rearrange text from a txt file to another with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy and edit some text from one text file to another using python.
I've been looking around and found some simple examples but still can't find everything I need.

My original text is something like this (starting with some text, then having a header line starting with NODE, followed by a line starting with `----`, and then comes the data that I am interested in):

```
[The file starts with a lot of text, which I have not includeded here ...]
 NODE DISPLACEMENT AND ROTATIONS DEFAULT PRINTOUT                      Unit System : kN , m

__________________________________________________


 NODE       LC               UX          UY          UZ          RX    RY          RZ
------ -------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------

   101      AW2  Max       0.005       0.000       0.001         0.0         0.0         0.0
                 Min      -0.007      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0

             LL  Max       0.021       0.000       0.002         0.0         0.0         0.0
                 Min      -0.031      -0.000      -0.003        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0

   102      AW2  Max       0.003       0.000       0.000         0.0         0.0         0.0
                 Min      -0.003      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0
```

I want my program to print the following:

```
   101,      AW2,  Max,       0.005,       0.000,       0.001,         0.0,         0.0,         0.0
   101,      AW2,  Min,      -0.007,      -0.000,      -0.000,        -0.0,        -0.0,        -0.0
   101,       LL,  Max,       0.021,       0.000,       0.002,         0.0,         0.0,         0.0
   101,       LL,  Min,      -0.031,      -0.000,      -0.003,        -0.0,        -0.0,        -0.0
   102,      AW2,  Max,       0.003,       0.000,       0.000,         0.0,         0.0,         0.0
   102,      AW2,  Min,      -0.003,      -0.000,      -0.000,        -0.0,        -0.0,        -0.0
```

This is my attempt, but it does not give the desired output. I don't know how to address this problem:

```
node = 0
with open("infile.txt",'r') as inFile:
    with open("outfile.txt","w") as outFile:
        lines = inFile.read().splitlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if "NODE" in lines[i]:
                node = node + 1
                if node ==2:                   #it is the line "NODE  LC  UX  UY  UZ  RX  RY RZ"
                    j=3                        #it is the line "101 Aw2 Max 0.005 0.000 0.001 (...)"
                    while lines[i+j] != "\n":
                        for word in lines[i+j].split():

                         nodenumber = word[1]
                         loadcase = word[2]
                         MaxMin = word[3]
                        #How can I make it work for everyline? (they don't all have the same structure)

                        outFile.write( ) #How do I create the output that I want with comas?
                        outFile.write("\n")
                        j=j+1
```

Comment: just a hint: you don't need to read the whole file in memory to read it line by line - just iterate directly over the file itself, ie `for i, line in enumerate(inFile)`. Even with today's computers available RAM, useless RAM usage can lead to MemorError when you have other processes competing for resources.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers! Great tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could use re to get the lines you want.

```
import re

lines = [

        ' NODE       LC               UX          UY          UZ          RX    RY          RZ',
        '------ -------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------',
        '',
        '   101      AW2  Max       0.005       0.000       0.001         0.0         0.0         0.0',
        '                 Min      -0.007      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0',
        '',
        '             LL  Max       0.021       0.000       0.002         0.0         0.0         0.0',
        '                 Min      -0.031      -0.000      -0.003        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0',
        '',
        '   102      AW2  Max       0.003       0.000       0.000         0.0         0.0         0.0',
        '                 Min      -0.003      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0',
    ]

for line in lines:
    if re.findall(r'(Max|Min)\s+\-?\d+\.\d+\s+', line):
        print(line)
```

result

```
101      AW2  Max       0.005       0.000       0.001         0.0         0.0         0.0
              Min      -0.007      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0
          LL  Max       0.021       0.000       0.002         0.0         0.0         0.0
              Min      -0.031      -0.000      -0.003        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0
102      AW2  Max       0.003       0.000       0.000         0.0         0.0         0.0
              Min      -0.003      -0.000      -0.000        -0.0        -0.0        -0.0
```

and with split() you can put the contents of each line in a list. With that it should be easy to to reformat the data to your wishes.

```
for line in lines:
    if re.findall(r'(Max|Min)\s+\-?\d+\.\d+\s+', line):
        line_parts = line.split()
        print(line_parts)
```

result

```
['101', 'AW2', 'Max', '0.005', '0.000', '0.001', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
['Min', '-0.007', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.0', '-0.0', '-0.0']
['LL', 'Max', '0.021', '0.000', '0.002', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
['Min', '-0.031', '-0.000', '-0.003', '-0.0', '-0.0', '-0.0']
['102', 'AW2', 'Max', '0.003', '0.000', '0.000', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
['Min', '-0.003', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.0', '-0.0', '-0.0']
```

formatted

```
col_1 = ''
col_2 = ''
for line in lines:
    if re.findall(r'(Max|Min)\s+\-?\d+\.\d+\s+', line):
        line_parts = line.split()
        if len(line_parts) == 9:
            col_1 = line_parts[0]
            col_2 = line_parts[1]
            line_parts.pop(0)
            line_parts.pop(0)
        elif len(line_parts) == 8:
            col_2 = line_parts[0]
            line_parts.pop(0)

        str = '{:>4s}, {:>4s},'.format(col_1, col_2)
        for line_part in line_parts:
            str = str + '{:>8s},'.format(line_part)
        str = str[0:-1]
        print(str)
```

result

```
 101,  AW2,     Max,   0.005,   0.000,   0.001,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0
 101,  AW2,     Min,  -0.007,  -0.000,  -0.000,    -0.0,    -0.0,    -0.0
 101,   LL,     Max,   0.021,   0.000,   0.002,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0
 101,   LL,     Min,  -0.031,  -0.000,  -0.003,    -0.0,    -0.0,    -0.0
 102,  AW2,     Max,   0.003,   0.000,   0.000,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0
 102,  AW2,     Min,  -0.003,  -0.000,  -0.000,    -0.0,    -0.0,    -0.0
```

Comment: Hi Mace, thanks for your help! I really can't use the import lines as you have, because it changes everytime and the file has 519113 lines, which I want to import some. The onlythings are equal everytime (but are not always in the same line of the file) are the headers! That's why I was looking up for "specifi words"!

Comment: the split part may help me, but I need to write in the lines that don't have info, the node number and the loadcase. (the second line should apear: ['101', 'AW2', 'Min', '-0.007', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.0', '-0.0', '-0.0']

Comment: The lines are only for the example. I don't have your input file. Can you use re? As mentioned you can use the list to format to your wishes. I will add some code to the example.

Comment: Great. There are many ways to structure your program.If you first put the found lines in a list and split and process them later on, then you can also put markers for your specific words in the list when you find them. When processing the list it should be easy to find the parts you need.

Comment: There was an error in the example. It should be 2 times pop(0) instead of pop(0) and pop(1). I have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

better to use pandas to read text file in data frame using built in method pandas.read_csv()

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimiter = '\t', lineterminator ='\n')
```

you might need to use some more arguments according to file type like utf-8 or something else
and fill columns

```
df[column_name or number].fillna( method ='ffill', inplace = True)
```

the above code will right the value whatever is in the upper cell

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the first thing I tried, but it is a very big file (593000 lines) with a lot of different structures... columns with numbers, text,explanations, ....

Comment: Better to NOT use a 800 pounds gorilla package designed for tabular data operation (csv IO are just a by-product of panda's features) when all you need is the stdlib's csv package (which IIRC is what panda uses for csv formats) - or even simple string formatting operations FWIW.